# How to style Material UI Dialog with Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

Material UI Dialog is a portaled component. The way I understood it and saw it in action is that it renders its markup outside the React's `root` element.

It renders itself before the `</body>` tag.

Now I have encountered a problem because of this.

When user chooses the dark mode, I set a dark class on top-level element, one beneath the root element.

And on all components I can use dark variant to apply styles, like `dark:bg-zinc-700`.

But when I apply it the `<Dialog />` component, it won't affect its style, though I can see that the class exists in the output.

```
<Dialog
    PaperProps={{
        className="dark:bg-zinc-700"
    }}
```

How should I solve this problem? I know I can use `sx` to apply style. But that means I need to lose consistency and I also don't know how to translate Tailwind to `sx`. Thus I prefer to keep using Tailwind.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem with this [Link](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33424)

```
MuiDialog: {
    defaultProps: {
      container: rootElement,
    },
 },
```

Check this

Answer (score 1):

@HosseinFallah Looking back at your post I think this won't work because tailwind and material ui handle dark modes differently. However, you can target Material UI css without using sx. You can use the [Dialog API classes](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/#css) in your css and apply tailwind colors on them like this in your global css:

```
.MuiDialog-paperScrollBody {
background-color: theme(colors.dark) !important;
}
```

Where `dark` is the custom dark color you've set in your tailwind.config.js

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer you can also set this for your whole app by wrapping it with the Mui's StyledEngineProvider. This way tailwind will be prioritized when injecting styling.

In your `index.tsx`

```
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material';

const container: any = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <React.StrictMode>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                <App />
            </StyledEngineProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    </Provider>
);
```

Then this will be possible without needing to specify `!important`

```
<Dialog
    PaperProps={{
        className="dark:bg-zinc-700"
    }}
```

Comment: It's not a problem of priority. It's a problem of scope. Dialog is rendered outside the root element. Dialog is not a child of the root element. There is no parent in the Dialog HTML that contains the `dark` class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "important" property in the Tailwind config (tailwind.config.js) by chance?

If you set it to something like "#root" then it will only match the elements inside the #root element which is bypassed when MUI uses React Portals.

You could change it to something like "#tw" and then set your body's ID to "tw" so it will always match since Portals are always children of the body element.

Answer (score 0):

if you completely interoperate to tailwindcss, see: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css
i think this mistake occure in tailwindcss.config.js.
by adding another id to wrap dialog container and asign it to "important" property will solve this problem[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can increase the specificity of the TailwindCSS by using `!important` selector.

You can find more here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives

Comment: It's not a problem of priority. It's a problem of scope. Dialog is rendered outside the root element. Dialog is not a child of the root element. There is no parent in the Dialog HTML that contains the dark class.